# GWT Grid - Column Reordering On the Fly and Sort By Multiple Columns

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, grid

Several months back, I did some searching for a GWT based grid, which would meet a couple of requirements. If memory serves me correctly, I found what I was looking for, however now that I'm searching for it again, I can't seem to find it.

The requirements were as follows:

1. One was that it could sort by multiple columns (e.g. Shift Click one
   column then the other and it'll sort by the first one first and 2nd
   as a sub sort (e.g. Last name then first name sort)).
2. The next requirement was that I could drag and drop the column order
   on the fly. Meaning that the user could change the order of the
   columns by simply dragging and dropping the column headers to the
   left or right of others.

Please let me know if you know of such a component/library/etc, as it'll save me lots of home cooked code :)

**Some Side Notes:**

Smart GWT meets Requirement 1, but doesn't allow for the column reordering (
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_header_span )

Answer (score 0):

I found something simliar to what I was looking for: http://datatables.net/extras/colreorder/

I'm going to look to see what it costs and if it fully meets everything I'm looking for. If others know of things just as nice, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting lib, almost looks like GWT's CellTable - but that doesn't look like a GWT library...

Comment: BTW, GXT 3's Grid can do #2, but can't do #1. That said, I think you can implement shift-click support for sorting with your own event handlers. Only catch would be column indicators for 1, 2, 3, etc, not sure right away how you would do that.